# IntelliJ Gradle project, no test runner tab

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I try the spock test framework with IntelliJ (2021.3.2), created the demo from https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/tutorial-spock-part-1-getting-started/ with the first simple test.

I don't see the test runner tab (even if I could run the tests). The Gradle configuration is set by default to run tests by using Gradle. If I switch the Gradle configuration to run tests using IntelliJ IDEA, I got the test runner tab.

How could I get the test runner tab with Gradle too?

Comment: With the sample project available at https://github.com/trishagee/spock-testing-demo the tests work just fine: https://i.imgur.com/D4HQD3E.png. We can't reproduce the described issue. If it still doesn't work for you, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the exact steps to rerpduce it, a video of the issue and the logs attached using Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: If I create the project from scratch, all seems as expected. Even if I use the demo from Git, I have the test runner tab even if the tests are executed by Gradle. With the previously created test project I got now no clear result. I will watch if I got the same behaviour again.